# Using js onclick on one button to inject link into another

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have two buttons, both without links, and want to add a link to one when the other is clicked. How can I make one button with an onclick give a link attribute to something else on the page? If not a button, maybe a div?

The following is my current code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:#000000 !important;">
<img id="myImage" src="images/closed.png" style="width:100%">
<p id="texthere"></p>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='images/open.png'" class="btn btn-primary active btn-block">Open Eyes</button>
    </div>
<div class="col">
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='images/closed.png'"class="btn btn-primary active btn-block">Close eyes</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

*Edited to clarify and pose as a question.

Comment: Link in a button? It is not permitted content in a [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).

Comment: Not a proper question

Comment: Didn't understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be confused about how HTML links work. HTML has the `a` tag for elements that a user can click to go to a different URL. The (worse) alternative is to use an `onclick` handler to redirect the user by setting the value of `window.location`.

To make a button that creates a link on the page, put a `script` tag at the bottom of the body that attaches a listener to a button that, when called, places a link on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var button = document.getElementById('my-button'); // This button has to exist.
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = 'google.com'; // Or wherever you want the link to point.
        document.body.appendChild(link);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you- I did not *think* I was confused with the purpose and general use of the tag- I was trying to have a link attribute be given to an object, but only after a particular onclick event to add the link to the button, but I think that may have more to do with how I asked the question, so I'll work on clarifying in the future. Thank you for your response as well- very helpful and gets me closer.

Answer (score 0):

While there are many ways to do what you want, without knowing what programming skills you have and what you want to see on the screen, perhaps this sort of structure would help you. Replace your current onclick handlers on the BUTTONs:

```
<button id="open" class="btn btn-primary active btn-block">Open Eyes</button>
<button id="close" class="btn btn-primary active btn-block">Close eyes</button>

<script>
document.getElementById("open").addEventListener("click", function() {
    changeState('open');
});

document.getElementById("close").addEventListener("click", function() {
    changeState('closed')
});

function changeState(state) {
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = 'images/' + state + '.png';
    var new_para = document.createElement("p");
    var new_link = document.createElement("a");
    new_link.setAttribute("href", "https://www.google.com/search?" + state);
    var new_link_text = document.createTextNode("Search for '" + state + "'");
    new_link.appendChild(new_link_text);
    new_para.appendChild(new_link);
    document.body.appendChild(new_para);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Sorry for the delay in response but this essentially provides the answer I was looking for.